# Possible combinations with conditions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So i was looking for some time for something i could learn this in my language without success, and this is my last hope i guess.

Let's go straight to the examples:

Let's say i want to know all possible combinations on EU digital clock (**24-hour cycl**e). HH:MM:SS

But with a condition where **H1 < H2 ≤ M1 < M2 ≤ S1 < S2**.

Another example be i want all possible combinations of 
**x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 < 50**

but **x1 + x2 + x3 = 10** and **−1 ≤ x1, 2 ≤ x2, −3 ≤ x3, 4 ≤ x4, −5 ≤ x5 ≤ 5, 6 ≤ x6, −7 ≤ x7 ≤ 7**

Thanks for your answers in advance and sorry if i overlooked a thread where similar problem is already solved.

Edit: some source where i could learn this stuff would do.

Comment: @A student What you want to find??

Comment: Number of all possible combinations of all variables